# 'Could not find this item' error message on new hard drive

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, filesystems

I have recently put a new hard drive in my laptop, and rebuilt my laptop from scratch, and now I get the following messages anytime that I try to create a file/folder or copy files/folders onto anywhere on this hard drive.

> Could not find this item. This is no longer located in [path]. Verify the item's location and try again.

But the weird thing is, after this I click the 'Try Again' button and it works perfectly.

Is there anyway to avoid these error messages?

**System details:**

- Windows 7 Professional, 32bit
- 500GB, 7200rpm HDD
- Laptop is hp 6730b
- I have also split this hard drive into several partitions if this makes a difference.

Comment: I'm fighting this exact problem on a laptop right now. Win7 Pro 32bit, 128GB SSD, Dell Latitude E4200. I can create a file and immediately try to rename it or move it but get the error titled "Item Not Found", "Could not find this item. This is no longer located in ..." It does not matter if I choose Try Again or Cancel... the file will usually be renamed but sometimes not. It happens with files and folders, both new and old. It happens under all user profiles, new or old. It isn't a problem for a file unlocker app to solve, especially considering most of the time the file does get renamed.

Comment: Also, the problem happens in any folder on any SATA or eSATA hard drive. Not just C: and not just on the Desktop. I have not yet tested it on USB-connected hard drives or thumb drives.

Comment: I don't know how you "disabled" your AV, but it is just about impossible to do while it is still installed. It loads a rootkit-like driver at boot and that is just the beginning. Services are often still running and protected from closure. If your AV has services, besides the other methods you used, disable them before rebooting next time to reduce the footprint of the AV at least.

Comment: @Abraxas, wrong question perhaps?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

People complain that this is due to windows update [KB980408](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/980408). But does not seem to be the case in all scenarios. I am not sure how up to date your install media of 7 is so this may not work.

Try a system restore to the point with no updates and see if that works. Bad news is you will probably auto get that update again :(

Also there is a reference to a registry fix [Here](http://www.techjawa.com/2010/05/01/guide-fix-windows-folder-renaming-could-not-find-this-item/)
You may want to check it out.

It seems to work for some people.

Good Luck

Comment: I can't test this to see if it fixes mine yet, but since it worked for DanieL, I'm giving harper89 the +50 bounty. I've searched high and low and this is the first one that seems to match exactly the problem I'm having, so I'll cross my fingers.

Answer (score 0):

If the nw drive is a SATA, perhaps the speed should be reduced to 1.5 GB/sec by using a jumper. It is possible that the system is falling behind the drive.

Are your environment variables all intact? Hopefully, no registry cleaners that may have caused damage?

And definitely run chkdsk /r on the drive. Even new ones can have problems. If you can run it from the recovery environment, that is best. But the results can be found in the Event Viewer if you run it from Windows.

Having multiple partitions will slow the system considerably, but should not have this type of effect.